# Adding rule to Treesitter LR1 grammar changes precedence

Tags: parsing, lr1, treesitter

I am trying to get operator precedence correct in a Treesitter grammar. Treesitter is a LR1 parser generator.

I have a straightforward artithmetic grammar, which partially looks like this:

```
multiply_expression: $ => prec.left(2, seq(
    $._expression,
    '*',
    $._expression,
)),

addition_expression: $ => prec.left(1, seq(
    $._expression,
    '+',
    $._expression,
)),
```

This works correctly. `multiply_expression` indeed gets a higher precedence than `addition_expression`.

However, the precedence changes when I add an intermediate rule:

```
_partial_multi: $ => seq(
    $._expression,
    '*',
),

multiply_expression: $ => prec.left(2, seq(
    $._partial_multi,
    $._expression,
)),
```

I moved `$.expression, '*'` to its own rule. To me, this seems to be an equivalent grammar, and I expect no changes. However, with this change the precedence is no longer correct. `addition_expression`, which remained unchanged, seems to have a higher precedence than `multiply_expression`.

Why does introducing an extra step change the precedence? Is there a name for this problem, or where can I find more information about it? When writing a grammar or fixing precedence problems, are there rules to follow or ways to think about this?

Comment: I don't know the details of how treesitter reoorts and resolves conflicts, but it seems to me that you haven't told the parser generator how to resolve conflicts involving `_partial_multi`. You should assign a precedence to that production.

Comment: Also, as usual it would be much easier to help you if you included a [mre] in your question. An extract is not easy to test.

Comment: Having said all that, I made a vague attempt to fill in a test file, and applied the suggestion I made in the first comment. It appears to work. The original test (based on your excerpt) simply parsed incorrectly, as you reported; no ambiguity warning is issued. (With bison, which uses a different way of configuring precedence, a conflict report is issued for your grammar.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your full grammar, for reproducibility:

```
module.exports = grammar({
  name: 'github_example',

  conflicts: $ => [],

  rules: {
    source_file: $ => $._expression,

    _expression: $ => choice(
      $.number,
      $.multiply_expression,
      $.addition_expression
    ),

    number: $ => /\d+/,

    _partial_multi: $ => seq(
        $._expression,
        '*',
    ),

    multiply_expression: $ => prec.left(2, seq(
        $._partial_multi,
        $._expression,
    )),

    addition_expression: $ => prec.left(1, seq(
        $._expression,
        '+',
        $._expression,
    )),
  }
});
```

You can fix this issue by adding precedence to the `_partial_multi` rule and removing left-associative precedence from the `multiply_expression` rule:

```
   _partial_multi: $ => prec(2, seq(
        $._expression,
        '*',
    )),

    multiply_expression: $ => seq(
        $._partial_multi,
        $._expression,
    ),
```

What you've done here is make multiplication a right-associative operator of precedence 2. This is how you define left- or right-associativity in grammars which don't expose it as a primitive. You can make multiplication left-associative by writing it as follows:

```
    _partial_multi: $ => prec(2, seq(
        '*',
        $._expression,
    )),

    multiply_expression: $ => seq(
        $._expression,
        $._partial_multi,
    ),
```

You've actually stumbled across something quite interesting, which is that you don't need explicit language constructs to define precedence & associativity in a grammar! They're just "syntactic sugar" to make the grammar easier to read & write. See [this page](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/5220/spr16/Notes/CFG/precedence.html) for more information on how to specify precedence & associativity by decomposing rules. You can see that specifying precedence & associativity purely through grammar constructs is confusing, and almost reads backwards from what you expect unless you think about it! As you also discovered, mixing these two approaches (specifying precedence & associativity through language constructs *and* grammar constructs) can lead to confusing behavior. It is best to stick with one or the other.